# Can't add property to MeshVertex

Tags: python, add-on

I have a prop class

```
class Jbeam_NodeProps(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    name = StringProperty(name="ID",description="", default="")
    group = StringProperty(name="Group",description="", default="main")
    selfCollision = BoolProperty(name="Self Collision",description="", default=True)
    collision = BoolProperty(name="Collision",description="", default=True)
    nodeWeight = FloatProperty(name="Weight",description="", default=50.0, min=0.0, max=10000.0)
```

I add it to the vertices type like so in the register function

```
bpy.types.MeshVertex.jbeam = PointerProperty(name="Jbeam node settings",type=Jbeam_NodeProps)
```

But I obtain this which isn't usefull to store or display the informations

```
(<built-in function PointerProperty>, {'type': <class 'io_mesh_jbeam.Jbeam_NodeProps'>, 'name': 'Jbeam node settings'})
```

PS: This addon is to make a sort of skeleton for an external game engine

Comment: BeamNG? What is your question here?

Comment: Yes it's for BeamNG, I want to had custom properties to vertices, edges and faces